# reading a string from resx file sharpdevelop c#

Tags: c#, resx, sharpdevelop

I'm writing a class library in C# using sharp develop. I am including an resx(resource) file which contains some string values. I'm using the following code:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("ResourceFileName",this.GetType().Assembly);
string str=rm.GetString("Keyname");
```

It compiles fine. At run time, it gives me the following error:

> Could not find any resources
>   appropriate for the specified culture
>   or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "ResourceFileName.resources" was
>   correctly embedded or linked into
>   assembly "myassembly" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies
>   required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

The question is that is it not possible to use resx file in Sharpdevelop?? If yes, then how to resolve this problem.

Thanks and Regards,
Vamyip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first argument use full name of resource class "namespace.classname"
in secound argument

```
 Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```